# SSIS package .csv Issue - Package not recognising the cell is a number, how to convert

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, ssms, visual-studio-shell

I'm trying to input a .csv file it a table within SSMS.  On the whole, I've got this working for me, however, the very fist column in the .csv file is data type 'General', and the data inside it is a number is is showing as 1.01E+12, when really the number is 1012345693210

I need this to go into the table as a full number, however when the SSIS package I have previews the data, it shows as 1.01E+12, and also when it imports ot into the table

I need this to be a full number as this number will be used in a join going forward within a script I'll be creating off the back of the table,

How do I change this without changing the .csv file?  I cannot change this unfortunately as this comes from an outside source and we do not control the file, and the file will be used to update a table daily so it needs to be correct as it goes in

Would this be a Data Conversion at all within the Data Flow between the Flat File Source and the Table destination? If so, could someone please help explain how as I'm not 100% familiar with it

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean it has the data type "General"? `General` is neither an SSIS or SQL Server data type. Sounds like you're importing it as a string data type, not a `bigint`/`int64` and thus getting a floating point value.

Comment: So on the csv file, when I click on the number, the data type/Number format is 'General', and this is a number and needs to be converted to a number within the SSIS package to show in the table, as currently I think it is trying to show it as a string, and when I try to change this to a int, either Four Byte or Eight Byte Signed  Integer, it still shows in the preview of the Flat File Connection Manager as 1.01E+12

Comment: What's the data type of the column you're importing into?